# Aapt2.exe stopped working,How to solve it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I had Started building an app in android studio 4.0 on windows 7 64 bit .In that it doesn't show any error while writing code but when i start debugging the app in my real device it shows error that Aapt2.exe stopped working.can anyone guide to solve this problem?

**Errors**

Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
> Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
> > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.
> > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during compile 'C:\Users\Admin.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png', attempting to stop daemon.
> This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

**And second error**

AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output:

[image of Aapt2 window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FPBc.png)

can anyone help?

Comment: common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png what is this error coming from here

Comment: i m beginner so i don't have knowledge about it but the error while showed by android studio i copy pasted it so above is what android studio showed me

Comment: Check your drawable folder and for this or paste a github link or drive link where we can see your code and try to resolve

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16rb9JuuNHGNhSN4A-ewNYA-POt7qJIx3?usp=sharing

Comment: just create a authentication page

Comment: It also showing same while building apk

Comment: I am checking wait please

Answer (score 0):

Okay paste this in your manifest file and check you call the theme out of Application

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.codewithabhy.howsapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="ExtraText"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.HowsApp">
        <activity android:name=".OTPActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".PhoneNumberActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: no it is showing error while building  the project

Comment: .Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.

Comment: > AAPT2 aapt2-4.1.1-6503028-windows Daemon #0: Compile 'C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal_background.9.png' timed out, attempting to stop daemon.

Comment: This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform play-services-base-17.1.0.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:17.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Users\Admin\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d92a27efcac738b4f280b9ad0c07bda7\jetified-play-services-base-17.1.0.

Comment: it shows the Aapt2 stopped working check online solution and close and close program

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the newer AAPT2 version (which comes with newer AGP) having a dependency on up-to-date Windows universal C runtime libraries. If you don't have them yet, download from Microsoft's website, if you already do - see if there's an update available (even if you have to do it manually). Microsoft is doing a gradual roll-out of the updates, but sometimes they take longer for certain systems/architectures.

Comment: But I am working  on windows 7 will it work

Comment: I think so, there are available on https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by changing below lines in `gradle` file project level

```
//       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1'
```

and from :

```
kotlin_version = '1.5.0'
```

to `kotlin_version = '1.7.10'`